# Save EditText value onResume()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, activity-lifecycle

I'm trying to save the value of EditText when I rotate the device. 
I am using Firebase Database to save and get my values.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            if (mPostKey != null) {
                titleEditText.setText(post.getTitle());
                notesEditText.setText(post.getNotes());
            } else {
                titleEditText.setText(prefs.getString("titleText", post.getTitle()));
                notesEditText.setText(prefs.getString("notesText", post.getTitle()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
    mPostListener = postListener;
}
```

This works only if the the value is not stored already in the firebase.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prefs.edit().putString("titleText", titleEditText.getText().toString()).commit();
    prefs.edit().putString("notesText", notesEditText.getText().toString()).commit();

}
```

I could set the orientation change in the manifest, but if I do that, when I add a photo to the activity, I still loose the text.

I have also tried to remove the listener before and after super.onResume() like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mPostListener != null) {
        mPostReference.removeEventListener(mPostListener);
    }

}
```

Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Can you please give me an example, because I've tried doing this as well, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Did you Try To use this Override Function

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation== Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {

        }
        else  if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to work. If there is a better answer please share it with me.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    mPostReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
            if (mPostKey != null) {
                titleEditText.setText(post.getTitle() + prefs.getString("titleText", post.getTitle()));
                notesEditText.setText(post.getNotes() + prefs.getString("notesText", post.getTitle()));
            } else {
                titleEditText.setText(prefs.getString("titleText", post.getTitle()));
                notesEditText.setText(prefs.getString("notesText", post.getTitle()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

and in onResume

```
   @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prefs.edit().putString("titleText", titleEditText.getText().toString()).apply();
    prefs.edit().putString("notesText", notesEditText.getText().toString()).apply();

}
```

EDIT

This method doesn't set the text correctly if I edit in front of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `savedInstaceState()` for that purpose. Example:

```
// This function will invoked when rotation detected
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("titleText", titleEditText.getText().toString());
    outState.putString("notesText", notesEditText.getText().toString());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // this will restore it
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        titleEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("titleText"));
        notesEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("notesText"));

     }
}
```

I think this better because it will never save it like `SharedPreferences` does

Comment: this works only if the database is empty. if it's not, it overrides it with the value from firebase. any suggestions ?